# jQuery Smooth Scroll Current/Active

Tags: jquery, scroll, smoothing

I'm using jQuery Smooth Scroll on a one page website, and each "panel" has the nav at the top right. I would like to show the currently selected "panel" by highlighting that selection in the nav each time the user changes "panels". Is there a somewhat simple way already built into the plugin to do that? Thanks!

[jQuery Smooth Scroll website](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each of your nav button share the same class (such as `.navbutton`) but have a different id (such as `#nav1`,`#nav2`,`#nav3`), you could create a new class in your css (lets call it `.selected`)

```
.selected {
    background: red;
}
```

Then, when you execute your code that does your scrolling, also do this:

```
$(".navbutton").each(function(){ $(this).removeClass('selected'); }); // remove selected from all Nav Buttons
$("#nav1").addClass('selected'); // Add class to single Nav Button (assuming nav1 was clicked)
```

Comment: I ended up not needing this functionality, but thank you for the response. It looks like your code would work if I needed it though. Thanks! :)